# How do I use subnumcases correctly?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, cases

I have been trying to use subnumcases to get numbers for each line of a picewise defined expression, and using labels to be able to easly refer to them later with links but I keep getting the following error:  Missing $ inserted. Missing $ inserted. for the last line of subnumcases.

```
\begin{subnumcases}{\langle\xi_\lambda ,\, \xi_\lambda \rangle =}
$0$  & for $|\lambda| > N$, \label{aa} \\
$(2N+1)^{-1}$ & for $|\lambda| \leq N$\label{bb}.
\end{subnumcases}
```

Do I have to notify LaTeX that the last line is in fact the last line in some way? If I put another \\ it will create a third line in the bracketed picewise definition which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The left column in `subnumcases` is typeset in math mode, whereas the conditions are in text mode. So you need to remove the `$` characters in the left column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{\langle\xi_\lambda ,\, \xi_\lambda \rangle =}
0           & for $|\lambda| > N$,    \label{aa} \\
(2N+1)^{-1} & for $|\lambda| \leq N$. \label{bb}
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively (and preferably, in my opinion) use `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{global}
\begin{empheq}[
  left={\langle\xi_\lambda ,\, \xi_\lambda \rangle =\empheqlbrace}
]{alignat=2}
&0           &\qquad& \text{for $|\lambda| > N$,}    \label{aa} \\
&(2N+1)^{-1} &\qquad& \text{for $|\lambda| \leq N$.} \label{bb}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is it preferable? Because `cases` is an ingenious hack, whereas `empheq` uses the standard `amsmath` machinery.